# Looking for some way to save array in file - like a numbers (now program saves all like a text)

Tags: assembly, tasm

```
xor    ax, ax
mov    tab[100], '$'
mov    ah, 3ch
mov    cx, 00000000b
lea    dx, filename1
int    21h
jc     openerr
mov    handle, ax
mov    ah, 40h
mov    bx, handle
mov    cx, 100
lea    dx, tab
int    21h
jc     openerr
mov    ah, 3eh
mov    bx, handle
int    21h
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please show us what is the definition of the data at *tab* is.

Comment: tab dw 100 dup(0)
it contains numeric values 1-1000

Comment: With that definition your program is already saving the array **as numbers**, no text is involved!

Comment: its saving kod in ascii for example when tab contains 65, 66, ...next 98 numbers, program will save AB######... but im need to save 65 66 ###

Comment: Now you're telling that you do indeed want to save as readable text. Question: do you want a space character in between the numbers "65 66" ?

Comment: yes - i can even put them one by one to some temp string add just add space, but dont now how to change it - it always takes it like chars when im trying save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an outline of what you need to do:

- read one value from the array,                       number 65
- convert this value to its text representation,       string "65"
- add a space character,                               string "65 "
- write the result to the file,                        use CX=3
- repeat the previous for all the values in the array, repeat 100 times

The conversion is the hard part, but you can find many good examples everywhere including on this forum.